# React state taking previous initialized values when updating

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue with react.

I have an array of states of a task whether it is pending or completed or running.
I have an used an array in use state like this

```
const [messageState, setMessageState] = useState<string[]>(new Array(6).fill('Pending...'));
```

All that has been initialized to pending first.
And then the messages come from Kafka and according to that, I am updating the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
       if(message.info && message.info.log.indexOf('fromScript') ! == -1) {
       const {info} = message
       const {err} = info
       for(let i=0; i < 6; i++){ 
       const array = setTableContent(i, err)
       console.log(array);
       setMessageState(array)
 }
 }
  }
)
```

The function for setTableContent is

```
const setTableContent = (row: number, err: any) => {
    const value = getStatus(row, err);
    const newArray = [...messageState]
    newArray[row] = value;
    return newArray; 
  }
```

where getStatus is a function which fetches the status for all the tasks on every kafka message.

Now the problem is that every time even if I am updating the state of messageType in useEffect snippet, I am still getting the same initialized values on the 3rd line of setTableContent function. Why is this happening I am not able to understand.
Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: this for loop of yours will not have any iterations, as it starts from 9 and condition to stop loop is <6
`for(let i=9; i < 6; i++){ ..`

Comment: Sorry. Have edited that now.

Comment: still other mistakes and unclear things in the code
you're asking why state isnt updated, but you don't have `setMessageState` called anywhere (just `setMessageType`).
messageType that you use in setTableContent is not defined anywhere.
Also I don't think you intended to call setMessageType in a loop on each iteration..

you can set up a working example e.g. on jsfiddle reproducing the problem, this way it will be easier for someone to help you

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure why I can't update an array state in a loop but I have found a turn around for this.
Rather than putting

setMessageState() in useState, i have put the for loop in the function setTableContent() itself.

```
const setTableContent = (row: number, err: any) => {
 const values = []
 for(let i=0; i < 6; i++) {
   values.push(getStatus(i, err));
}
setMessageType(values);
 }
```

And now its working